# How to pass a session attribute as method argument (parameter) with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In short, I want something like:

```
public String action(@SessionAttribute User user) {..}
```

instead of

```
public String action(HttpSession session) {
     User user = session.getAttribute("user");
}
```

Mainly for the sake of:

- readability
- unit testing

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213974/spring-mvc-session-attribute-access

Comment: Are session-scope beans not what you need?

Comment: no. How would I pass them as method parameters? And I can't inject them, because the controller is singleton.

Comment: You can inject them using `<aop:scoped-proxy>`

Comment: well, yes, but I want something like `@RequestParam`, only for session - the difference isn't so big :)

Comment: Does it have to work for arbitrary session attributes, or is it ok to let Spring manage putting them in to the session as well as getting them out?

Comment: better handle everything. I found a solution, see my answer :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a [solution](http://karthikg.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/learn-to-customize-spring-mvc-controller-method-arguments/).

The idea is to register a custom [`WebArgumentResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html) for the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, which handles a custom annotation - `@SessionAttribute` (or `@SessionParam`).

One note to the code posted there is that `param.getParameterName()` can be used if no `value` is specified.

Comment: What if you have @SessionAttribute(required = false) User user. The default value that is returned as a string doesn't match with User. Can you manage that somehow?

Answer (score 4):

For those arriving via Google, as of at least 4.3.2.RELEASE, Spring includes a [`@SessionAttribute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttribute.html) annotation built-in:

```
public String action(
    @SessionAttribute(required=false, name="user") User user) {

    // ...

}
```

A custom solution is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we use @ModelAttribute("user") User user as the method parameter and then use user object in your method it will have updated user from session. The attribute name has to match with the session attribute name "user".

```
public String myMethod( @ModelAttribute("user") User user ){

 System.out.println(user.getDetails());

}
```