# Session attribute as method argument with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using [Bozho solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621266) to create a session attribute annotation under Spring mvc.
I've a problem when the object is not in the session and I've something like

```
@SessionAttribute(required = false) MyFormObject myFormObject
```

The annotation is defined as

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface SessionAttribute {
    String value() default "";
    boolean required() default true;
    String defaultValue() default ValueConstants.DEFAULT_NONE;
}
```

I get an exception since `defaultValue()` returns a `String` and my custom `ArgumentResolver` tries to assign this `String` to `MyFormObject`.

How can I instruct Spring to assign `null` to `myFormObject` instead of `ValueConstants.DEFAULT_NONE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you simple modify the custom `WebArgumentResolver` to return `null` instead of `defaultValue` when attribute is not found?

Answer (score 0):

the `defaultValue` can be the username of the user, which you can find by injecting a dao into the resolver. But having a default user doesn't make much sense anyway, so just return null