# How can I bind JSP page and session scoped field of the controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple controller with scope annotation.

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private User user = new User("Bob");

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and simple jsp page

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Y=${sessionScope.user}</h1>
    <h1>Z=${user}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I'm trying to run this code, I'm getting nothing. The result is empty. I don't want to use single beans of `User`, also I don't like to pass object of `HttpSession` to method in controller or `HttpServletRequest` object for retrieving session from it. Is there any solution for using some annotation (except `@SessionAttributes`) to pass object to jsp from my controller?

Comment: From your given code, you don't have any `sessionScope` attribute in any scope to be found: page, request, session, application. Instead, you may have a `${helloController}` if ever initialized.

Comment: Is ${helloController} already in session?

Comment: As I've said, it will be if ever initialized.

Comment: ever = never? I don't follow you either to be honest.

Comment: You may consider the answers submitted to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276391/spring-3-mvc-expose-session-scoped-bean-in-mvc-controller-method-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you are surprised. The only thing in your code that is in the `HttpSession` is the `@Controller` bean.

Just because that object has a field of type `User` doesn't mean there will be a `User` attribute in the `HttpSession`.

> The result is empty. I don't want to use single beans of `User`, also I
>   don't like to pass object of `HttpSession` to method in controller or
>   `HttpServletRequest` object for retrieving session from it. Is there any
>   solution for using some annotation (except `@SessionAttributes`) to pass
>   object to jsp from my controller?

You've basically listed all your options. Use any of those.

Comment: I thought there are another options.

Comment: @user3279337 You could always make one yourself, Spring is customizable that way. But somewhere down the line you will need to call `HttpSession#setAttribute(..)`.